# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yad2k.models'

Tags: yolo

I am getting this error while I trying to import libraries for Yolo implementation for the practical implementation given in this article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/practical-guide-object-detection-yolo-framewor-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Darknet

1. In the case of windows you have to Manually build if you want gpu support
2. in Linux or mac you just have to run make file present in darknet
   As I can guess your issue could be because of this make file